# Flutter build fails on large files [Dart snapshot generator]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dart app, where I use machine learning to process some data. Therefore I use code generation to export my ML model into pure dart. It always worked fine, however lately, I retrained the model and the generated file was very large (**roughly **150k** lines**). Now when I want to build the apk, the dart **snapshot generator consumes all my RAM (128GB!) and failed with exit code 9**. I swapped out only the one large file with an earlier version, where it was much smaller, and it works again (only after cleaning :D).

I tried to annotate the function in the file and the class with `@pragma('vm:never-inline')` according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71953861/dart-snapshot-generator-failed-with-exit-code-6), but this does not work either.

Is there any way to compile such a large file or do I have to somehow modify the file itself?